Questions regarding the proof of the Rayleigh’s equation has at least one limit cycle
This comes from the book Classical Mechanics by R.Douglas.Gregory
In page 207, we are given an equation known as The Rayleigh equation
$$x'=y$$
$$y'=-x-\epsilon y(y^2 -1)$$
and the book aims to prove that The Rayleigh’s equation has at least one limit cycle.
The book states that the above system of equations in polar form is given by :
$$r' = -\epsilon r sin^2\theta (r^2 sin^2\theta -1) $$
$$\theta' = -1 - \epsilon sin^2 \theta (r^2 sin^2\theta -1)$$
However , after i did my own calculations, i get the following results:
$$r' = -\epsilon r sin^2\theta (r^2 sin^2\theta -1) $$
$$\theta' = -1 - \epsilon sin \theta cos \theta (r^2 sin^2\theta -1)$$
Here are my calculations:
Since we are given
$$x'=y$$
$$y'=-x-\epsilon y(y^2 -1)$$
and we want to transform it using polar coordinates, let $x=rcos \theta$ and $y = rsin \theta$.
Then since $x$ and $y$ are functions of a variable $t$, we differentiate $x=rcos \theta$ and $y = rsin \theta$ to get
$$x' = r' cos \theta - \theta' r sin \theta$$
$$y' = r' sin \theta + \theta' r cos \theta$$
So
$$\begin{pmatrix} cos \theta & -rsin \theta \\ sin \theta & r cos \theta \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} r' \\ \theta' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} r' \\ \theta' \end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{rcos^2 \theta +rsin^2 \theta } \begin{pmatrix} rcos \theta & rsin \theta \\ -sin \theta & cos \theta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}= \frac{1}{r}\begin{pmatrix} rcos \theta & rsin \theta \\ -sin \theta & cos \theta \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} =\frac{1}{r} \begin{pmatrix} rx'cos\theta +ry'sin\theta \\ -x' sin\theta + y'cos\theta \end{pmatrix} $$
Substituting $x'=y$ and $y'=-x-\epsilon y(y^2 -1)$
to the above matrix, we will get
$$\begin{pmatrix} r' \\ \theta' \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{r}\begin{pmatrix} rx'cos\theta +ry'sin\theta \\ -x' sin\theta + y'cos\theta \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{r}\begin{pmatrix} r(y)cos\theta +r(-x-\epsilon y(y^2 -1))sin\theta \\ -(y) sin\theta + (-x-\epsilon y(y^2 -1))cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$
Substituting $x=rcos \theta$ and $y = rsin \theta$, we will get
$$\begin{pmatrix} r' \\ \theta' \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{r}\begin{pmatrix} r(rsin \theta)cos\theta +r(-rcos \theta-\epsilon (rsin \theta)(r^2sin^2 \theta -1))sin\theta \\ -(rsin \theta) sin\theta + (-rcos \theta-\epsilon (rsin \theta)(r^2sin^2 \theta -1))cos\theta \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\epsilon r sin^2\theta (r^2 sin^2\theta -1) \\ -1 - \epsilon sin \theta cos \theta (r^2 sin^2\theta -1) \end{pmatrix}$$
Here is the original text from the book:

Also the book gives the following proof:




Questions:
1)Is there something wrong with my calculations? Because i cant get the polar form in this book

2)Why is the path not possible to be closed?
The explanation of Gregory:
Phase paths that begin on either of the straight segments of the outer boundary $C_2$ enter D and can never leave. These phase paths cannot close themselves (that would mean leaving D) and so can only tend to a limit cycle.
But I don't understand the paragraph above, because the path is already closed according to the picture above.

After 4 long years, it’s time you read [$\tt MathJax$](https://math.meta. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Note that if you take the derivative of the second equation, you get $$0=y''+ϵy'(3y^2-1)+y,$$ a version of the more widely discussed vanderPol oscillator.


I dont't find a  trusted reference, so I feed  the substitution to Mathematica for sure: Substitute x,y as pure functions, solve for $r',\theta'$
Solve[({x'[t] - y[t] == 0,                     
        y'[t] + x[t] + ε y[t] ( y[t]^2 - 1) == 0} /.
     {x -> (r[#] Cos[θ[#1]] &), 
      y -> (r[#] Sin[θ[#1]] &)} // Expand ) /.
{f_[t] :> f},
 {r', θ'}][[-1]]   //
 FullSimplify // Expand // TrigExpand // Simplify



\begin{align}
 r ' \ &= \ \varepsilon \  r \  \sin ^2(\theta )\   \left(1 \ - \ r^2 \ \sin ^2(\theta )\right)\\
 \theta '\ &= \ \frac{1}{8}\  \varepsilon \  r^2 \  \sin (4 \theta ) \ + \  \frac{1}{4} \ \varepsilon \  \left(r^2\ - \ 2\right) \  \sin (2\, \theta ) \ - \ 1 
\end{align}

Closed paths have to be differentiable curves. In canonical mechanics everything is invariant under canonical rotations in phase space. Sudden change in the tangent direction means either displacements in p (kick, reflection) or x (jump).


After 4 long years, it’s time you read $\tt MathJax$.

MathJax is not a tool to to verify algebra, as far as I know,  now CAS is the state of the art.  As you see, I am using  MathJax  perfectly feeding MMA output to WinEdt, edit for regular typesetting, control output via MiKTeX .  What 4 long years, apropos?
